# Not blocking off original domain when setting up BIND server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am trying to set up a BIND server so that I can access my office SFTP servers with the same address both locally and from outside the network. This has worked well, however after setting up the BIND server I am no longer able to access my site, (hosted by Linode), by its domain name from within the local network. I tried adding an A record on my local BIND server to direct potato.com back to the linode server, but that hasn't worked.

On Linode's end I've configured any subdomain (*.potato.com) to go to my businesses ip address.

I've included by configurations:

named.conf.local

```
zone "potato.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.potato.com"; # zone file path
    allow-transfer { 192.168.7.63; };           # ns2 private IP address - secondary
};

zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192.168";  # 10.128.0.0/16 subnet
    allow-transfer { 192.168.7.63; };  # ns2 private IP address - secondary
};
```

named.conf.options

```
acl "trusted" {
        192.168.7.62;    # ns1 - can be set to localhost
        192.168.7.63;    # ns2
        192.168.7/24;    # All?
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        recursion yes;                 # enables resursive queries
        allow-recursion { trusted; };  # allows recursive queries from "trusted" clients
        listen-on { 192.168.7.62; };   # ns1 private IP address - listen on private network only
        allow-transfer { none; };      # disable zone transfers by default

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
};
```

db.192.168

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     potato.com. admin.potato.com. (
                              6         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers
      IN      NS      ns1.potato.com.
      IN      NS      ns2.potato.com.

; PTR Records
62.7   IN      PTR     ns1.potato.com.    ; 192.168.7.62
63.7   IN      PTR     ns2.potato.com.    ; 192.168.7.63
70.7   IN      PTR     pickle.potato.com.  ; 192.168.7.70
80.7   IN      PTR     pork.potato.com.  ; 192.168.7.80
62.7   IN      PTR     office-rpi.potato.com.    ; 192.168.7.62
63.7   IN      PTR     suite-rpi.potato.com.    ; 192.168.7.63
```

db.potato.com

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.potato.com. admin.potato.com. (
                              7         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

; name servers - NS records
    IN      NS      ns1.potato.com.
    IN      NS      ns2.potato.com.

; name servers - A records
ns1.potato.com.          IN      A       192.168.7.62
ns2.potato.com.          IN      A       192.168.7.63

; 10.128.0.0/16 - A records
pickle.potato.com.        IN      A      192.168.7.70
pork.potato.com.        IN      A      192.168.7.80
office-rpi.potato.com.      IN      A      192.168.7.62
suite-rpi.potato.com.  IN      A      192.168.7.63
potato.com                  IN      A      555.555.555.555
```

Comment: "I am trying to set up a BIND server so that I can access my office SFTP servers with the same address both locally and from outside the network." why not just hardcoding your needed IP in `/etc/hosts`? You do not need to install a full nameserver just to map some hosts to specific IPs.

Answer (score 2):

Note that all your entries in "db.potato.com" end with a dot, e.g.

```
;                   V
suite-rpi.potato.com.  IN      A      192.168.7.63
```

This dot makes the domain name fully qualified. Since the dot is missing from your entry `potato.com` this name is *not* fully qualified resulting in the zone name being added to it. This will result in the domain name "potato.com.potato.com".

Add the missing dot and it should work.

```
;         V
potato.com.            IN      A      555.555.555.555
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. But was adding the potato.com domain the correct solution to begin with? It seems like a clunky way to do it, but I couldn't think of another way.